# Infinite summation 21

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Find 
$$\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{21}+\frac{1}{45}+....\infty$$
I tried to rewrite it as
$$S=\frac{1}{1\times3}+\frac{1}{2\times5}+\frac{1}{3\times7}+\frac{1}{5\times9}+.....$$

To identify the pattern but i could not go on

Comment: You can spot the pattern from that as $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n\cdot(2n+1)}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{2n^2+n}}$

Comment: Shouldn't be $\frac{1}{45}=\frac{1}{5\times 9}$ instead of $\frac{1}{4\times 9}$?

Comment: i have edited it , you are right @FrankLu

Comment: @HussienMohamed What is the pattern then? I don't see it.

Comment: @HussienMohamed do you have any other terms?

Comment: There is no apparent pattern to the terms here.  Each term is roughly half it's predecessor so it looks like it converges, but really that's just a guess based on too little information.

Comment: I do not have any other terms @RhysHughes

Answer (score 5):

This is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n(2n+1)}$. This series converges. Just use the comparison test with the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}$.

Comment: No, it is not this series; not after the OP's edit to the question.

Comment: Actually, what OP needs is the sum of the series.